# Functional programming for loop side effect

Tags: functional-programming, loops, side-effect

I am trying to get my head around as to why having a local variable or a for loop inside a function is not considered to be pure functional programming.

Given this function:

```
int as_int(char *str)
{
    int acc; /* accumulate the partial result */

    for (acc = 0; isdigit(*str); str++) {
        acc = acc * 10 + (*str - '0');
    }

    return acc;
}
```

Under what circumstances would the variable acc be a side-effect ? Even in a concurrent environment each invocation of the function would have its own copy of acc. So I don't quite get why it isn't allowed in functional programming.

Comment: There are no side-effects. See: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/196112/in-functional-programming-are-local-mutable-variables-with-no-side-effects-stil?rq=1

Comment: `as_int` is a pure function, but the code within it isn't pure.

Comment: Pure code is usually associated with immutable variables. `acc` is mutable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looping in functional programming isn't done with control statements like `for` and `while`, it's done with explicit calls to functions like `map`, `fold`, or recursion - all of which involve placing the inner loop call *inside another function*. If the loop code mutates variables outside the loop, this inner loop function would be manipulating variables outside its scope and would thus be *impure*. So the whole outer function is pure, but the looping is not. Looping constructs in functional programming require you to make the state explicit. Translating your code to something using functional programming looping tools reveals the impurity:

```
int as_int(char *str)
{
    int acc = 0; /* accumulate the partial result */

    map(takeWhile(isdigit, str), void function(char *chr) {
      acc = acc * 10 + (chr - '0');
    });

    return acc;
}
```

*(Note - this syntax is approximate to get the general idea across)*

This code uses an inner function for the loop body which must mutate the variable `acc`, which is outside it's scope. This is impure - the inner loop function *depends on the outer loop context*, calling it multiple times with the same character will have side-effects, and the order you call it on the sequence of characters matters. In functional programming, in order to make this a pure function you would have to make this dependency on state passed between loop iterations explicit with `fold`:

```
int as_int(char *str)
{
    return fold(takeWhile(isdigit, str), 0, int function(char *chr, int acc) {
      return acc * 10 + (chr - '0');
    });
}
```

`fold` uses a function of two arguments for the inner loop body: the first argument is an item in the sequence that `fold` is looping over, while the second is some value that the inner loop body uses to build up partial results. For the first loop iteration, `acc` is 0, for the second, `acc` is whatever the first inner loop function call returned, for the third, it's whatever the second inner loop returned, and the final loop returns the result of the whole `fold` expression.

Note that this isn't really a problem with your code from the perspective of the rest of your program - both definitions of `as_int` are pure. The difference is by making the inner loop code a pure function, you can take advantage of the massive array of tools functional programming offers to decompose the loop into something more declarative (e.g. using takeWhile, fold, filter, map, etc. etc.)

Comment: +1. Among the advantages of using high-order functions such as `takeWhile`, `fold`, `filter`, `map`, (i.e. declarative style) is that you also stop thinking in terms of "Compute something by destructively updating memory locations". In this way, the result does not depend on the history / exact sequence of the computation steps.